# Can I use my UK Business visa for tourism?

Tags: visas, uk

I was granted a multi-entry Standard Visitor visa last July for business purposes. I know the business visa does not exist anymore, but I still have the following on my visa stamp:
Type of visa: C
Remarks: C-visit

The project I was supposed to fly to the UK for has been postponed until February, so I haven't had the chance to use my visa.
Now, I want to spend a week end in London in January, just before my visa expires, but I don't know if this is possible.

More info:

- I am still working for the same company.
- If I go, I will be travelling with my boyfriend who is Spanish and does not need a visa. We both live in Spain.
- I have e-mails stating that the project has been postponed and will be resumed in 2017.

Comment: My visa was not issued prior to April 24, 2015. Plus, it my stamp states "c-visit" even if the rules have changed, so I'm not clear on that either.

Comment: Do you live with your boyfriend? Have you lived together for more than 2 years?

Comment: We have been living together for some months now, less than a year though.

Comment: Once you have lived together for two years, if the UK is still in the EU or otherwise participating in its freedom of movement regime, you will be able to travel to the UK under those rules if you are accompanying or joining him. That doesn't help you in this case, of course.

Comment: See also https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/407476/HC_1025_Immigration_Rules.pdf

Comment: Do you know what "type:c" and "remarks:c-visit" stand for?

Comment: Answering my own question, it might help others. I went to the UK. No issues there. I was asked about the purpose of my visit in the border and said that i was visiting london for tourism purpose. Everything went just fine.